# How to show/hide TextView in android xml file and java file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have TextView in one of my layout. I want keep it hide and only want to make it visible when button is clicked, how can I do it ? My view is like below.
Thanks.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/textAuthorSign"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="- ABJ Abdul Kalam"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thanks

Comment: set the visibility in your onClickListener for your button. Ie: txtView.setVisbility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you want a toggle (As stated by the question title)

XML File:

```
     <Button
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/self_destruct"
         android:onClick="hide" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
         android:id="@+id/textAuthorSign"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:text="- ABJ Abdul Kalam"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:visibility="invisible"
         android:typeface="serif"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java:

```
 public void hide(View view) {

     TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAuthorSign);

     //Toggle
     if (txtView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     else 
        txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     //If you want it only one time
     //txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 }
```

Answer (score 7):

First get the reference to the textView:

```
  TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
```

Then

```
  textView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Hi ! and in XML I need android:visibility="invisible" ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct to initially have it invisible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setVisibility` method as of this example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAuthorSign);
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Will make your view visible and `View.INVISIBLE` will make your view invisible.

You can also do `View.GONE` and then the TextView won't take any space on the layout...

Comment: Hi ! and in XML I need android:visibility="invisible" ?

Comment: `android:visibility="invisible"` Indeed

Comment: Please mark as answered if my answer helped you...

Comment: if I remove android:visibility="invisible" , its always showing that text, I want only one time visible on action and than I need to keep it hidden

Comment: You want the text to become invisible right?
Than change the `View.VISABLE` to `View.INVISIBLE `
Also you may want to use `View.GONE` if you don't want your view to take actual space in the layout....